# Code never reaching if(DateTime.Now == myTime) value

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I have a simple (stupid) bit of code which I'm using to test our error logging mechanism. It attempts to read from a non-existent file. On exception, I set a DateTime value, then I have a while loop. Once the current DateTime is equal to the DateTime value I set, then I pass the exception to my error logging project.

This code starts on a button press. The purpose of this is that I can test what happens when multiple exceptions are thrown from separate user sessions in my ASP.NET application.

So I'd open a few browser sessions, press the 'Exception' button then this code will run. Once the current time matches up with the time I set, then it *should* throw an exception, but the `if(DateTime.Now == run)` never evaluates to true. Why?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    { 
        DateTime run = new DateTime(2013, 12, 18, 14, 0, 0);
        bool hasRun = false;

        while (hasRun == false)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now == run)
            {
                ErrorLogger errorLogger = new ErrorLogger(ex);
                hasRun = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that the expression `DateTime.Now == run` will ever evaluate to true, don't you think? Given that `DateTime` is accurate to a 10,000th of a millisecond?

Comment: Agreed, there are some fundamental issues here. DateTime.Now is extremely accurate, and so it's highly unlikely it'll ever match up unless you get very, very lucky.

Comment: In other words - use a `>` rather than `==`...

Comment: @AntP Very true (but DateTime is actually _slightly less accurate_ than that)

Comment: The 'run' DateTime object we created, we're only specifying it down to the second value. It goes year, month, day, hour, minute, second then DateTime.Kind. Millisecond isn't specified so surely it should evaluate to true so long as the second value is the same?

Comment: I don't understand why you have the time portion anyway.  What difference does it make if `new ErrorLogger(ex)` runs at the moment the except is thrown or 30 seconds (or 30 minutes) later?  Why not just remove that?

Comment: @CiaranGallagher You did not set miliseconds, but `DateTime.Now` does. Imagine comparing the two doubles `1.0` and `1.1` and expecting them to be equal because you set `.0` in the first one.

Comment: Jon, put that in an answer, that's exactly it. I was actually using that previously, somehow escaped my notice to use that...

Comment: @CiaranGallagher: No, because DateTime.Now IS accurate to the millisecond.  Is 1.12345 == 1.123456?

Comment: Right, perfectly explained. Thank you.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher - A [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.aspx) is basically a nicely dressed `(U)Int64` counting the ticks since 0001-01-01. If you create it like that, all the time parts you don't specify will automagically be set to zero.

Comment: Any time you have a question about whether code is executing or not, set a Breakpoint a couple lines before that and step through the code. Then you can see the values and see for yourself exactly what is going on. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @msm8bball, absolutely I should have done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if(DateTime.Now >= run)

similar trap as in checking for equality with float or double

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, somehow didn't occur to me :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just does not take into account the fact time will never be rounded to seconds. there is always miliseconds. If you want to compare, just use this snippet

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
date = new DateTime(date.Year,date.Month,date.Day,date.Hour,date.Minute,date.Second)
if (date == run)
{
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `Timer` leads to clearer and less risky code (no loops which might go infinite):

```
catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    // The hard-coded date should of course be a *future* one for the code to have sense
    var interval = new DateTime(2013, 12, 20, 09, 00, 00) - DateTime.Now;

    Timer t = new Timer(interval.TotalMilliseconds);
    t.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
    {
        ErrorLogger errorLogger = new ErrorLogger(ex);
        t.Stop(); // Let it only run once
    };
    t.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out for the if condition:

```
if (Datetime.Now.Subtract(run).Days == 0)
{
    // code goes here if the run and Datetime.Now are on the same day
}
```